# Re-structure JavaScript Object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JavaScript object being created from PHP through a MSQL query.

However, the JavaScript object isn't exactly how I need it.

JavaScript Object:

```
  var data = [{"name":"Ashley","latitude":"51.46619000","longitude":"-2.58345600","type":"% respondents who go to work (as driver) by car","percentage":"25.3","year":"2013"},{"name":"Ashley","latitude":"51.46619000","longitude":"-2.58345600","type":"% respondents who go to work by walking","percentage":"37.7","year":"2013"},{"name":"Avonmouth","latitude":"51.49275700","longitude":"-2.68259000","type":"% respondents who go to work by train","percentage":"0.0","year":"2013"},{"name":"Avonmouth","latitude":"51.49275700","longitude":"-2.68259000","type":"% respondents who go to work by moped\/motorbike","percentage":"1.2","year":"2013"}...etc];
```

The above is just a sample of it, there are a total of 35 different ward "names" and there is a separate one per each type i.e. "% respondents who go to work (as driver) by car", for each name.

I need it to have one object per name and all the types and percentages to be in a sub array. For example:

```
var data = [{"name":"Ashley","latitude":"51.46619000","longitude":"-2.58345600”,"types":[{“type”:”% respondents who go to work (as driver) by car”,”percentage”:”25.3”,”year”:”2013”},{"type":"% respondents who go to work by walking","percentage":"37.7","year":"2013”}}...etc]},{"name":"Avonmouth",...etc}];
```

Is there a way I can re-structure the object in JavaScript? So it essentially merges the data, so there are no repeating name objects and puts all the types into a sub array per name.

**Edit:**

I've tried various solutions from stackoverflow such as:

```
var res = {};

$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    if (!res[value.name]) {
        res[value.name] = value;
    } else {
        res[value.name].type = [res[value.name].type, value.type].join(',');
    }
});

data = $.map(res, function (value) {
    return value;
});

console.log(data);
```

This does remove all duplicate "name" objects so then there is only one for each ward name so there is only 35 objects (which is right). But only keeps one type and percentage and removes the rest for each name.

Comment: Yes, it requires a few simple lines of code, have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes you can. What have you tried so far? Show us your code.

Comment: I've added a solution I've tried above.

Answer (score 0):

Aman, Oh man!
You are overriding your `type` instead of `push`ing to it..

Try this..

```
$.each(data, function (idx, value) {
    var type = value.type;

    if (!res[value.name]) {
        res[value.name] = value;
        res[value.name].type = []
    }

    res[value.name].type.push(type);
});
```

Ok, it doesn't handle the other fields you need, but it should point you to the logical bug you have in your code.. any further work you should be able to do by yourself..